# How to generate a key file out of a .cert?

Tags: ssl-certificate, keys

I have received a p7b file from my co-worker and he asked me to install it on one of our servers. It looks like p7b is same as .cert file. I looked up google to find out how to install the file and it looks like I also need to have .key file.

Is it possible to make the key file with .cert or .p7b file?

Comment: No, there is no way to create a private key when you only have the public key.  The entire encryption systems rests on idea that you cannot do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Is it possible to make the key file with .cert or .p7b file?`

## No.

Some administrators keep the private key in the same file as the public portion of the certificate, however `.p7b` files do not contain private keys: they only contain the public key certificate & certificate chain.
You need the corresponding `.key` file to use the certificate.

---

As Zoredache said the entire point of public key cryptography is that you have two parts: A public half (`.cert` file) which encrypts data, and a private half (`.key` file) which lets you decrypt it again.

The contents of the `cert` file are given to everyone who connects to your server. It would defeat the purpose of encrypting data if that information were usable to *decrypt* the traffic too.

For more information refer to [the Wikipedia page on public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) and/or the page on [SSL/TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)